# How to reply to comments using closure_tree gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to ROR and am having serious issues with trying to create nested comments. In my app a user can create a post (wad). Each wad has many comments and every comment belongs_to only one wad. My resources are nested as follows:

```
resources :wads do
    member do
      put "like", to: "wads#upvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end
```

I am able to post, edit and delete comments, however when I try to reply I am getting a RecordNotFound error. The app is rerouting to the incorrect page i.e. `/wads/comment_id/comments/new` but I believe that it should be redirecting to `/wads/wad_id/comments/comment_id`. Here are my create and new methods from my comments controller:

```
def create
        if params[:comment][:parent_id].to_i > 0
            parent = @wad.comments.find_by_id(params[:comment].delete(:parent_id))
            @comment = parent.children.build(comment_params)
            @comment.save
        else
            @comment = @wad.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:content))
            @comment.user_id = current_user.id
            @comment.save
        end

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to wad_path(@wad)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end



    def new
        @comment = Comment.children.create(parent_id: params[:id])
        @comment.save
    end
```

This what I use to link to reply: `<%= link_to "Reply", new_wad_comment_path(comment) %>`

I have perused the answers to similar questions on stackoverflow for days but none of the answers have worked for me. Can somebody PLEASE help me with this issue.

routes:

```
new_wad_comment GET    /wads/:wad_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_wad_comment GET    /wads/:wad_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            wad_comment GET    /wads/:wad_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
```

find_comment method:

```
def find_comment
    @comment = @wad.comments.find(params[:comment_id])  
end
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tree order: 'created_at DESC'
  belongs_to :wad
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Wad Model:

```
 class Wad < ApplicationRecord
      acts_as_votable
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
      default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
      validates :user_id, presence: true
      validates :category, presence: true
      validates :long_form, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1000 }
      validates :short_form, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
      validates :problem_state, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    end
```

Comment: Did you include the has_many and belongs_to in your models?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hashrocket - yes those relationships are properly defined

Comment: What routes do you get when you run rake routes?

Comment: @hashrocket thanks for that - I just edited the post to include the relevant routes I got when I ran that. I assumed that edit_wad_comment path is the one I needed and so swapped it in but now I am running into an error with a line in my find comment method

Comment: Edited post to include find_comment method. The error is "Couldn't find a comment without an ID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you’re using a nested route, you have to pass the wad along with the comment in your link_to call. Something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_wad_comment_path(wad, comment) %>
```

The wad in the link_ to will supply your route with the wad_id it is looking for.

Comment: This fixed that - thank you. I will definitely mark your answer as correct, while I have your attention though. It seemed that the path I actually needed was new_wad_comment path instead. I've configured my reply button to redirect to the corresponding URL for that path and on that page I have a form that is posting comments no problem. The issue is now that the comments are being posted individually and without the nested relationship? Any tips on where the error might be?

Comment: I’m not understanding what you’re trying to accomplish. Are you saying that the comment is not showing on the wad show page?

Comment: The comment is not being saved as a child of the parent comment

Comment: Are you passing the wad and the comment to the form? If you’re not, the form doesn’t know what wad to give the comment to.

Comment: I fixed my routing and I am able to post comments, link to reply and post new comments, but it's not making the parent child relationship between comments. No idea what I am doing wrong but that probably warrants a new question by itself

Comment: Try creating a new comment in the Rails console and see if the comment has a wad_id.

Comment: It has one if I assign one to it. When I run Comment.new all the keys come up including wad_id and parent_id

Comment: What is parent_id?

Comment: parent_id should be the comment_id id of the comment that is being replied to. I've defined it in my controller and with the link_to reply but I haven't been able to get the reply comments to inherit the parent_id. I am thinking it might be where I'm sending the form

Comment: What do your models look like?

Comment: I just updated the post to include comment and wad model

Comment: I still don’t understand where you’re getting the parent is from. You should have a wad_id and a comment_id.

Comment: I added the parent_id column to the comment table as I was following this (https://www.sitepoint.com/nested-comments-rails/) tutorial. The only thing that is different with my app and the tutorial is that my comment model belongs to another model. Is this an inefficient way to get nested comments??

Comment: Is there a way to pass the id of the root comment to the parent_id column of the reply comment?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the closure_tree gem, but let me take a look at it and see if I can help you.

Comment: I've managed to get reply comments to inherit parent_id, but now the issue is that the values of comments are being input into the database as null. The server log to create a comment is INSERT INTO "comments" ("wad_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "parent_id") - it's ignoring the id and content columns for some reason